# How to increase video quality/Resolution in OpenTok RTC(Real Time Communication)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, opentok, tokbox

I am using OpenTok iOS SDK (Multi Party Call Demo). How can I increase video quality?
I am having high speed internet connection during video call but video quality is not so good as it should be.

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Are you using routed or relayed sessions?

Comment: @MarkVeenstra I have created session using Relayed Media Mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the iOS publisher side, the OpenTokRTC avoids that complexity as it is a demo app - but you can see:

1. Where [OpenTokRTC creates OTPublisher](https://github.com/opentok/OpenTokRTC-iOS/blob/master/webrtcDemoiOS/RoomViewController.m#L50):
2. In a different sample app, an example [custom OTPublisher](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples/blob/develop/2.Lets-Build-OTPublisher/Lets-Build-OTPublisher/TBExamplePublisher.m#L41) that uses a custom VideoCapture.
3. Where the custom [VideoCapture](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples/blob/develop/2.Lets-Build-OTPublisher/Lets-Build-OTPublisher/TBExampleVideoCapture.m#L52) sets the resolution.

Combining these, you should be able to re-factor OpenTokRTC to use a custom OTPublisher where you can specify the resolution.

On the JS desktop publisher side, this is where OpenTokRTC creates the [webcam publisher](https://github.com/opentok/OpenTokRTC/blob/master/public/js/room.js#L62).
Here is the JS documentation for setting [webcam resolution](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/publish-stream/js/#setting_resolution).

Comment: I customised OTPublisher but now problem is that my audio is repeating , means whatever I say I listen back. which should not be. Can you please suggest any fix. I instelled OpentokRtc app from iTunes and it is working fine with no audio repeatition problem.